# Conditional grepping

Tags: shell-script, awk, scripting, grep, pipe

I have a config file and its content looks something like below:

```
    Jobname|Type|Silo|Description
    #comment1
    #comment2
    job1|me|silo1|test_job1
    job1|me|silo1|test_job2
    job1|prod|silo1|test_job3
```

Now I need the conditional content of the file, say the content with TYPE =me.
For this I am using a grep with me:

```
      job_detail=$((cat config_file | grep me | awk '{print $4}'))
```

In this case, I am getting the first line also , as JOBNAME is getting matching character me. 
I escaped comments with -v options. I can't comment the first line of the config file, as it is used by other unknown processes.

Is there a way i can grep the whole word match? would be better if there is a way to grep whole word with a particular character as condition.

A way to divide the line with '|' and then grep?

Comment: Why not just `awk -F\| '$2=="me" {print $4}' config_file`?

Comment: @steeldriver... thanx...  this works,  but suppose i need "me"  to be resolved from a variable,say $region,  how this should be applied with above?

Comment: `awk -F\| -v region="$region" '$2==region {print $4}' config_file`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
awk -F\| -v select="$var" '$2 == select { print $4;}' config_file
```

where

- `$var` contains the field you want to select
- -F\| tell awk to use | as separator, | (pipr) must be escaped.
- -v select="$var" transfer $var to awk variable (select)
- `$2 == select` select line whose second arg is "$var" or select.
- `{ print $4;}` print fourth field.

Comment: wow....  thanxs @archemar....   - v select worked like a charm for me...  thanxs again

Answer (score 0):

`man grep` will show you the `-w` flag:

```
-w, --word-regexp Select only those lines containing matches that form whole words. The test is that the matching substring must either be at the beginning of the line, or preceded by a non-word constituent character. Similarly, it must be either at the end of the line or followed by a non-word constituent character. Word-constituent characters are letters, digits, and the underscore.
```

Or, stick `| egrep -v Jobname` early in your pipline.

Answer (score 0):

A variation of [Archemar's solution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/247308/116858) which assumes that the `me` that you want to search for is `$LOGNAME`, i.e. the username of the current user:

```
awk -F '|' '$2 == ENVIRON["LOGNAME"] { print $4 }' <config_file
```

This would compare the second `|`-delimited field with the string in `$LOGNAME`, and if it matches it prints the fourth field.

To also explicitly disregard commented out lines:

```
awk -F '|' '$1 ~ /^#/ { next } $2 == ENVIRON["LOGNAME"] { print $4 }' <config_file
```

Answer (score -1):

I always prefer awk:

```
awk -F"|" '{ if ($2~/me/) { print $4 } }' myfile.txt
```

Comment: This would print the full line, not the 4th field, and it would additionally do that if the 2nd field was e.g. `meme`.